# Multimeter resistance reading bounces placed between earth ground and bench PSU

Tags: power-supply, oscilloscope

I'm a total beginner trying to understand how not to blow up myself, scope or meters.  I cannot figure out if probing around on a device powered using either of the two DC bench power supplies I have tried will cause a ground loop.  What's the proper way to test this?  What follows is what I tried.

I watched a video on EEVblog "How not to blow up your oscilloscope" (https://youtu.be/xaELqAo4kkQ?t=826) and at 13:46 he describes that bench DC power supplies are usually floating and often have a separate earth ground connector.  I went to verify on mine - a Riden RD6012 kit - that the negative terminal was not earth grounded similar to the way Dave did in the video. I measured the resistance to ground, expecting to see OL but that's not what happened.  Instead the multimeter flips between OL and auto-ranging something in the kilo-ohm range every half second or so (but the results are different when selecting ranges).  I bought another power supply - Wanptek DPS305U - that does have a discrete earth terminal and the results are different but just as ambiguous to me.

I have my power supplies and oscilloscope powered and grounded from the mains, and a portable battery powered multimeter, all turned on and connected in this way:

A probe is connected to the oscilloscope and its ground lead is always connected to COM on the multimeter.

These are the results (in auto-ranging mode) when the red multimeter probe is connected to each power supply terminal:

- Riden (-): 43 kohms  (see image)
- Riden (+): 44 kohms
- Wanptek: (-): flickers between OL and various values in kohms
- Wanptek: (+): flickers between OL and various values in kohms
- Wanptek: (ground/green): 0 ohms

When the polarity is switched at the multimeter and the black probe is connected to each:

- Riden (-): OL
- Riden (+): OL
- Wanptek: (-): flickers between OL and various values in kohms
- Wanptek: (+): flickers between OL and various values in kohms
- Wanptek: (ground/green): 1.2 ohms

[image: Example]

Comment: Please confirm scope and power supply are powered OFF!  Multimeter?

Comment: Can you turn off autoranging? Sometimes, a meter can drive you nuts as it seeks a suitable scale. I suspect some capacitive loads may cause this.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat  everything's on.  the multimeter is a klein mm2000.

Comment: Also, do these power supplies have separate feedback inputs for regulation?   (If so, you must guard against an open loop!)

Comment: By ground are you referring to the third pin or earth ground, not the neutral of the power system. Check to be sure your mains power system has a proper ground setup, if not that could cause some of your problems. Ground to ground should be at most a few ohms. Place your ohmmeter leads together and read the resistance, that value will be added to each reading.

Comment: @glen_geek Yes- some ranges show 0. some OL. At a certain kiloohm precision it goes up to about 12.5 kiloohms and down close to 0 kiloohms, cycling up and down over longish but sub-minute periods.  I guess what's surprising is that it isn't always measuring OL or some very high resistance level.  I think I'm grossly misunderstanding how to determine if the power source has a floating ground.

Comment: @Gil in the context of the oscilloscope leads I mean earth ground, and i can confirm it is earth grounded as I was instructed.  one of the PSUs (wanptek) has a green earth terminal and i can confirm it is 0ohm to earth ground as well.  when com and the ohm-meter terminal are connected together it reads 0ohm exactly.

Comment: @richard1941 I don't know what that means - can you point to a model that does and maybe I can research and compare?

Comment: Are you using autoranging or preferable set it on the lowest ohm range at least 2 ohms. Your riden shows no ground connection. Do you have to strap it?

Comment: @Gil the riden has a third terminal, and it is actually green, but it's not a ground terminal.  it's goes to battery charging circuitry.  it is powered by a 3 prong cord and the case is grounded to earth though.

Comment: @Gil  when i set the range to ohms it shows OL when measuring negative terminal to earth on both power supplies, but not when set to kiloohms as noted above.

Comment: That tells a lot, your ground is not as solid as we thought. If you short the multimeter leads you should get a very low reading, that will validate the leads are OK. How are you referencing earth.

Comment: SWITCH OFF! If there are any voltages present on the circuit, you cannot measure resistance sensibly. Your slow fluctuations suggest you're measuring AC voltages, not resistance.